# Problems getting an API through Dashing with ruby scripts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, dashing

I am new to Ruby and have been tasked with building a dashboard with Dashing which will display SiteUptime information, using our account API.
SiteUptime have sent me a suitable script, but it doesn't display anything on my Dashboard other than the Job name in text.

The konsole output is as follows while dashing is running:

```
scheduler caught exception:
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/backports-3.8.0/lib/backports/std_lib.rb:7:in `require_with_backports'
/home/support/projects/siteuptime/jobs/siteuptime.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:230:in `trigger_block'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/jobs.rb:204:in `block in trigger'
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-2.0.24/lib/rufus/sc/scheduler.rb:430:in `block in trigger_job'
```

I can provide the scripts, the erb, the rb, the coffee files etc but these can contain our API. Can anyone advise or help?

Comment: I do not understand, you are probably making a request for a controller in your API. Why is some job related to this?